# PHP DateTime diff returns wrong difference

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I calculate the difference of to queried dates. When the difference is lower than one month everything is correct. Here a example of a wrong result:

Query output:

```php
$row['start'] = '2018-08-06';
$row['end'] = '2018-09-26';
```

Code:

```php
$start = new DateTime($row['start']);
$end = new DateTime($row['end']);
$days = $start->diff($end)->format("%d");
```

Output:

```php
$days = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime difference is correct and the error only comes in when you are formatting the output. %d is the day of the month, not the total days in the DateInterval. These two datetimes are 1 month and 20 days apart. So %d only shows the 20 days part. %a should get you the total number of days.

A full guide to the format can be found here:
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! That returns the correct result.